# C# Android RunningAppProcesses returning App running when app is closed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` registered with `Services`. `OnReceive` method iterates through processes to check if our app is currently running.

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
            if (intent.Extras != null)
            {
                // get the incoming call state
                string state = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);

                // check the current state
                if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging)
                {
                    // read the incoming call telephone number...
                    string telephone = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraIncomingNumber);

                    // check the reade telephone
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telephone))
                    {
                        telephone = string.Empty;
                        return;
                    }

                    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);

                    foreach (var item in am.RunningAppProcesses)
                    {
                        if(item.ProcessName.Equals(appName))
                        {
                            Toast.MakeText(context, "Returning... " + item.ProcessName, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                            return;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Process name: " + item.ProcessName);
                    }

                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Telephone: " + telephone, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                    Intent intent2 = context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
                    context.StartActivity(intent2);
                }
                else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook)
                {
                    // incoming call answer
                }
                else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle)
                {
                    // incoming call end
                }
            }
        }
```

The `foreach loop` will return even when the app is closed, indicating the app still runs

Comment: you said that you itinerates throu proccesses to check if our app is currently running, so you access window task manager--processes? When app is closed, your code check the app still runs, so can you go to task manager--processes and see if the app is still running or other?

Comment: Indeed, the service registered does that through a broadcastreceiver.
And it detects that the app is running even tho the app is closed.
Is it due to the registered Services?

Comment: ,You can try to check after closing the app for a while to see if there is any change.